# Showing a correct answer when someone selects a wrong one

Tags: ios, objective-c

Okay so I am new to objective-c and have used a couple different tutorials to build my first app that is a quiz. I had it completely done and I was somewhat satisfied.. then I realized that if someone selects the wrong answer it doesn't show them what the correct one is. So I have been trying to figure it out for a little bit. So I created a new label That stays hidden until an answer is chosen.

Is there an if statement I can use that can utilize the text I set buttons to? For example:

```
switch (QuestionSelected) {
    case 0:
        QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question One"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"Answer number 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Answer number 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"Answer number 3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"Answer number 4" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer1Correct = YES;
        break;
```

This is what a question looks like within the category. My Answer1-4's are the buttons. And the Answer1Correct (depending on the answer) is a BOOL statement.

Is there a line that I can use in an if statement saying something along

```
if (Answer1Correct == YES) {
    CorrectAnswer.text = [NSstring stringWithFormat:"@?", Answer1]; (The question mark would be for text the button was set to. I know that @i, can be used for integers but I don't know if I can use the text a button was set to)
```

I know that won't work but I am trying to wrap my head around how a lot of the valuables work. For instance, the problem I see is that within my questions I have BOOLs, and the only way it activates the BOOL is dependent on what they choose. For instance if they chose Answer2 in that previous statement it just sets runs my wrong answer one because this is what I have for the buttons

```
-(IBAction)Answer1:(id)sender{

if (Answer1Correct == YES) {
    [self RightAnswer];
}
else{
    [self WrongAnswer];
}
```

And then the same thing for the following three buttons.

I know I am probably all over the place but the reason I started this was to try and learn how to understand it. So how can I establish what is Correct when they choose the wrong one and how could I make the label show accordingly. I am not asking to be spoon fed, this is my first fully functional app that doesn't really have a full purpose other than myself trying to put things together and understand how things work together. So a little explanation or where I can read up on what is going on would be more appreciated then just an answer. I probably need to give a little more information so if I what I am asking doesn't make sense please ask. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: Hey, 

Welcome to Objective C, it's a little confusing to start with so well done for persisting. I am not too sure what you are looking for with regards to an answer? Is it just that you want to dynamically set a string? as mentioned here "[NSstring stringWithFormat:"@?", Answer1]" in which case you could use "[NSstring stringWithFormat:"@%@", Answer1]" or just "Answer1" if this is already an NSString. If you could advise exactly what you want to do a little clearer I am sure me  or someone else can help :)

Comment: Thanks! Right now my ViewController has basically a Label that is set to be the question that it gets assigned and 4 buttons that will input the 4 multiple choice answers. When you select one of these answers, the buttons are set to .hidden and the only thing that is displayed is a separate label that says "Incorrect" or "Correct." I want to add an additional label underneath that that will display the correct answer. What confuses me about this is that within my switch I have the four BOOL statements. So all it is doing is establishing a YES or No depending on the correct answer.

Comment: I don't think that is is saving the Correct answer because they are BOOLS, so how can I make a label that utilizes what was correct to input into my label. I edited what my Right and wrong answers are defined as, I feel like this is where I would establish my if statement, I just don't understand how to implement the CorrectAnswer when my Questions switch statement is only helping determine if the BOOL is a yes or a no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of the code it's difficult, however one approach would be to have an array with the correct values in for each of the questions you would need to set a strong reference to this to ensure that it's not dealloc'd by arc.

in your .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *correctAnswersArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabelForIncorrectAnswer;
```

in your .m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
self.correctAnswersArray   = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"answer one", @"answer two", @"answer three", @"answer four",nil];
}
```

this can be reference using

```
self.correctAnswersArray[i];
```

where 'i' is the int value you require from the array  - note that arrays are indexed starting at 0

With regards to your current conditional statement, you could set the label text using the array when you confirm if the answer is correct or incorrect so

```
if (Answer1Correct == YES) {
            [self RightAnswer];
        }
        else{
            [self WrongAnswer];
self.myLabelForIncorrectAnswer.text = self.correctAnswersArray[0];
        }
```

and so on for each of the conditionals amending the array index number for each 'else' condition

Comment: Once again thanks for the help. From what I have read up on regarding Arrays are that they can store a collection of other objects, but as far as implementing them I am unfamiliar with them. The biggest cutoff that I am having is understanding how my Answers within my switch are being saved. Let me go ahead and edit my original post and I will put more of the code into it. I think that once I can understand more on how I am actually saving the questions it will help me understand. For instance:
[Answer1 setTitle:@"Answer number 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
that is setting the button text

Comment: and each of the four buttons has a BOOL statement that is automatically set to NO. Within my switch you can see I have the four possible answers and at the end it sets the Correct answers BOOL to YES. (I.e Answer1Correct = YES;) I really appreciate your help, the more I am reading through this the more I am understanding, I am trying to learn what exactly is going on rather than just getting it to work.

Comment: Yes thats correct, so within an array it can contain the strings of text that relate to your correct answers,  you could call this array in the current conditional statement , will edit my answer with an example

Comment: The more I read through this the more I am beginning to understand. As far as actually having the label set using storyboard, is it being done through the .m or am I still setting up a UILabel and setting it that way. I am sorry that I am still having a little trouble with it, but you are helping quite a lot. I don't know how to set the label text using just the array because I am only familiar with setting up UILabels and connecting them via storyboard. Oh, one thing is, is it possible to do this without having to update every single question?

Comment: Okay that's cool, so if you have your label in a storyboard and have it connected up via your .h file, you would change the text via the m. - so in my example 'self.myLabelForIncorrectAnswer' would be the connection so you would replace 'myLabelForIncorrectAnswer' with what ever your label is called. Basically when you connect something up from a storyboard to an implementation file, you can amend it's properties programatically as well as visually (on the storyboard) - hope that helps :)

Comment: I have over 700 questions in the quiz, I want to know if I add something that will take the established correct answer from each question and place it in the label. So within my switch with the questions there is a case 0-200 in a couple of the categories.

Comment: does each button have the answer as it's title text? if so you could use that? you could access it from the sender? let me know if thats the case and I will give an example of how to access the buttons text via the sender

Comment: I knew that you can do it that way, but I am not sure I have done this correctly. So am I just labeling the Label with the name and implementing the code. So technically with your code would I could just put the name of my label as "myLabelForIncorrectAnswer"? as far as my .h the @property would go within the interface, correct? I thought I understood, but when I went to use it I lost all sense of comprehension. Haha. I would love to be able to IM with you if that would be quicker. If not I understand if I am a lost cause with this. Am I just missing something?

Comment: No that's exactly it,  when you declare it in the .h you are assigning  'getters' and 'setters' which enable you to get and set properties on the object. This is done in the .m file, so yeah, if your label is declared as 'myLabelForIncorrectAnswer' and connected up then you just refer to that where you need to set its value

Comment: I have updated the example to show the .h property and changed the object name in the implementation

Comment: So for using this array what is changing the Label to the correct answer? So within my Category I have 200 cases 0-199. How would this change the label per case depending on what the correct answer is? I put up the full code for my category in the question.

Comment: I guess it's the initWithObjects is what is throwing me off. when I put "Answer 1" "Answer 2" "Answer 3" "Answer 4" In my switch they are all depending on what the possible multiple choices are and are different depending on the case.

Comment: Hey so the array would be instantiated at when the view loads, this would only contain the correct answers, the index of the array is how you reference that answer, so you know that if you are question 1 you need to call the first object in that array 'self.correctAnswersArray[0];' which would return the string with the correct answer in, question 2 would be 'self.correctAnswersArray[1];'

The initWithObjects, basically means, 'once the array has been allocated some memory, initialise it with the following' - NS arrays have to be set with data initially, they are also unchangeable once set.

Comment: self.myLabelForIncorrectAnswer.text = self.correctAnswersArray[0];
Okay so for this statement within is the 0 referring to the case number or just for each of the four if statements (one for each Answer1-4Correct). I was able to connect my label using this. Keep in mind I also have 5 different categories that use the same -(void) and -(IBAction)s. I hope I am not making a fool out of myself Just frustrating the crap out of myself.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send this to you so you could fully see what I am working with? If you don't have any more time (or patience) I understand and I will continue reading up on this. I can't express how thankful I am to have someone explaining this to me. It is a relief from trying to read it through the tutorials.

Comment: That's it, the 0 is just reference to the item in the array (1-4) so you could just amend that number for each of your cases